# Independent Set Problem Variant, Induction

Tags: algorithms, graphs

So the question gives us some mysterious algorithm, that given a graph G and an integer k, it outputs true/false to whether there is an independent set of size k in G.

So we have to design an algorithm that can call this mysterious algorithm within a polynomial number of times, to return an independent set of size k from G if it exists, or outputs impossible. The hint is induction.

I'm having trouble figuring an algorithm to solve this. I know however, that the proof for this algorithm involves removing or adding a vertex in the inductive step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Suppose you have a graph $G = (V,E)$ which is *yes*, and then there is a vertex $v \in V$ such that $G - v$ (the graph where you have removed $v$ from the graph) is *no*.  What can you say about $v$ and $G$?

Let us take an example, namely the following graph:

$G= (\{a,b,c,d\}, E=\{ab, bc, cd, ad, ac\})$

```
a —— d
| \  |
|  \ |
b —— c
```

and with $k=2$.  This is currently a *yes* instance.

First we ask:  If we delete $a$ from $G$, will the resulting instance still be a *yes* instance?

```
     d
     |
     |
b —— c
```

The answer is *yes*, this graph is still a *yes* instance.

Then we delete $b$ and ask the same question:

```
     d
     |
     |
     c
```

The answer is now *no*, this instance is no longer a *yes* instance.  Hence we cannot delete $b$.  Instead we try to delete $c$:

```
     d


b
```

The answer is *still yes*, and $|V(G')| = k$, so we conclude that $\{b, d\}$ is an independent set in $G$ of size $k$.

Comment: So I tried seeing if v is a vertex in the independent set. A toy example of 4 vertices connected in a square shape, with 1 edge diagonally through the middle, and searching for an independent set of size 2. When I removed a vertex that was previously part of the independent set, the resulting graph would return no, but yes for a removal of a non-independent set vertex. But then with a triangular graph on 3 vertices and k=1, the idea doesn't quite hold. I'm not sure if I am having a correct train of thought.

Comment: @RichardWeng What exactly was wrong with $K_3$ (triangle) with $k=1$?

Comment: I'm curious, what is the intuition for why this works? Because I can't seem to see why it works.

Comment: Oh I see, we have to remove all of v's neighbors as well in our induction if v is a candidate for the set.

Comment: Well, this is the way you construct a _solution_ from the _decision_ problem.  I don't know how to explain why it works, you just need to play around with examples, and maybe try to write a formal proof for it.  And obviously you have an oracle for the decision problem, so it's not something that normally works in polynomial time.